# Java System.in issue

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

           while (sc.hasNext()) {

               if (sc.next().equals("exit")){
                   System.out.println("EXITING");
                   System.exit(0);
               }  else {
                   System.out.println("IM STILL WORKING ok?");
               }

            }

    }
}
```

So here is a piece of code i was writing the other day to try and figure sth out (doesn't really matter what). The result of executing this code is :

eIM STILL WORKING ok?

eIM STILL WORKING ok?

exit

IM STILL WORKING ok?

exit

EXITING

Can somebody kindly explain why this has happened? I mean the fact the the Scanner didnt capture the first occurence of the word exit.

Answer (score 0):

This code is correct, and it works for me -- are you sure you've got the latest code compiled and running?

```
e
IM STILL WORKING ok?
e
IM STILL WORKING ok?
e
IM STILL WORKING ok?
ex
IM STILL WORKING ok?
exit
EXITING
```

Comment: java version "1.6.0_22"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_22-b04-307-10M3261)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.1-b03-307, mixed mode)
if you question my java version.   I really cannot reproduce it (the fact that i had to write "exit" twice)

Comment: No, I mean did you make any changes to your code since you last compiled it?

Comment: This is a hard to remember question... I honestly can't really tell. I don't remember. How is it connected to the fact that the Scanner didn't pick up the word exit?

Comment: Because the code you posted likely did not produce the output you've posted.

Comment: the only think that is not correct is that there is a blank line between exit and EXITING. sorry about that it was a formatting error while posting the question

Answer (score 0):

I think i know what the problem is . reproduced it right now... pressed several time a button for input (button e) followed by a fast return button (enter). This is why some lines have both the input and output. after that Scanner is unable to get the first occurrence of exit. It doesn't make that much sense to me tho as I think what I did shouldn't cause any trouble.